# How to select an element with a class that is not the first one with the class?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm sorry if the tile is confusing.

Basically, I have this:

```
<a href="#" class="active">one</a>
<a href="#">two</a>
<a href="#">three</a>
<a href="#">four</a>
```

When you click an a tag, it becomes active. I only want to know if any a tag besides the first one has an active class. Something like this:

```
if ($('a:not:first.active').length){
    //do something
}
```

It seems so simple but I just cannot figure it out

Comment: do you want to check whether there are 2 or more active elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient way of doing it would be this:

```
$("a.active:not(:first)").length
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
$("a.active").not(":first").length;
```

Comment: This is wrong actually. It selects second and so forth `a.active` elements; does not check if the element was the first a in the group.

Answer (score 0):

not sure this is what you are looking for

```
var $a = $('a');
if($a.filter('.active').not($a.first()).length){
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Pa9pc/)

Answer (score 0):

Seem like you want to add `active` class to the clicked anchor and remove this class from other anchors, if so, you can do:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings('a').removeClass('active');
})
```

without doing unnecessary steps like you're currently intend to do.

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/epp5s/)**